# how to install a package in yeoman project?

Tags: gulp, package, installation, bower, yeoman

I am new using yeoman, node, bower and gulp.

I have generated a project with yeoman. Now I want to add the chosen jquery plugin (https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) to my project. I have executed bower install chosen and I think that it has worked because I see now the plugin in the tree directories.

But, the question is, have I to modify package.json, gulpfile.js, bower.json or anything?

And after that, have I to write something in my html files? or should it be written in my html files automatically?

Int my html file I have 2 pieces of code:

```
<!-- build:css styles/vendor.css -->
<!-- bower:css -->
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

and

```
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js scripts/plugins.js -->
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/modal.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/button.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/popover.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

and I do not if i have to write something here or it should be automatic.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution in the documentation of bower https://bower.io/#getting-started